# redirect parked domain to wordpress landing page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've search for awhile here and can't find a working solution.

I am running the latest version of Wordpress and I want to take a parked domain and send it to a special Wordpress landing page like this:

Redirect: MyParkedDomain.com => MyMainDomain.com/welcome-parked-domain-visitor

Is this best achieved in a plugin or in an htaccess command, as I can't seem to get any of the suggested ones I've googled to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Post the .htaccess directives you've already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting this at the top of your .htaccess file in the document root of your MyParkedDomain.com doesn't work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?MyParkedDomain.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://MyMainDomain.com/welcome-parked-domain-visitor  [L,R]
```

Comment: I guess in all my searching, it wasn't made apparent that I should basically setup a second hosting account or add on domain and then put an htaccess in that account.  Your answer prompted me to discover / remember that, and this works just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I put this code in the .htaccess on MyMainDomain.com When I park a domain, I don't get any folder structure for my parked domain, all the traffic is just forwarded to the root of my main domain. But this now forwards that traffic to a sub-page perfectly.